# how to convert csv array object into json using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
data = [ 'Txn Date,"Value\rDate",Description,"Ref No./Cheque\rNo.",Debit,Credit,Balance',
  '1 Jan 2015,1 Jan 2015,"BY TRANSFER-\rNEFT*SCBL0036001*NB20501\r501011778*MR SELVAKUMAR\rAR-","TRANSFER\rFROM\r3199677044304",,"65,000.00","7,77,065.65"'
  ]
```

want to convert the above data format into `json` format .To do so i am using a split function i.e `split(",");` but i have `double` values that contains ",".

```
function csvJSON( tabledata){

    var lines = tabledata;//csv.split("\n");

    var result = [];

    var headers=lines[0].split(",");

    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

        var obj = {};



        var currentline = lines[i].split(",");


        for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){


                obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];



        }

        result.push(obj);

    }

    return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

this is what I am getting ,

```
{ 'Txn Date': '1 Jan 2015',
        '"Value\rDate"': '1 Jan 2015',
        Description: '"BY TRANSFER-\rNEFT*SCBL0036001*NB20501\r501011778*MR SELVAKUMAR\rAR-"',
        '"Ref No./Cheque\rNo."': '"TRANSFER\rFROM\r3199677044304"',
        Debit: '',
        Credit: '"65',
        Balance: '000.00"' }
```

And expected output:

```
{ 'Txn Date': '1 Jan 2015',
        '"Value\rDate"': '1 Jan 2015',
        Description: '"BY TRANSFER-\rNEFT*SCBL0036001*NB20501\r501011778*MR SELVAKUMAR\rAR-"',
        '"Ref No./Cheque\rNo."': '"TRANSFER\rFROM\r3199677044304"',
        Debit: '',
        Credit: '65,000.00',
        Balance: '7,77,065.65' }
```

how to solve this problem ,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the exact desired output.

Comment: Well it looks like your input format is pretty screwed up, you will have to parse it properly according to your needs. Note that your "doubles" are wrapped with quotes, so they are in fact strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to parse the csv [CSVToArray()](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm).

```
    function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){
        // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
        // then default to comma.
        strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

        // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
        var objPattern = new RegExp(
            (
                // Delimiters.
                "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

                // Quoted fields.
                "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

                // Standard fields.
                "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
            ),
            "gi"
            );


        // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
        // a default empty first row.
        var arrData = [[]];

        // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
        // matching groups.
        var arrMatches = null;


        // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
        // until we can no longer find a match.
        while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

            // Get the delimiter that was found.
            var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

            // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
            // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
            // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
            // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
            if (
                strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
                strMatchedDelimiter !== strDelimiter
                ){

                // Since we have reached a new row of data,
                // add an empty row to our data array.
                arrData.push( [] );

            }

            var strMatchedValue;

            // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
            // let's check to see which kind of value we
            // captured (quoted or unquoted).
            if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

                // We found a quoted value. When we capture
                // this value, unescape any double quotes.
                strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
                    new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
                    "\""
                    );

            } else {

                // We found a non-quoted value.
                strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

            }


            // Now that we have our value string, let's add
            // it to the data array.
            arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
        }

        // Return the parsed data.
        return( arrData );
    }
```

after that you only have to save the json